# Trapframe vs Scheduler Context in Process Management

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

So a process have scheduler context and trapframe and both of them are allocated in the kernel stack (kstack).

When process wants to transition from user mode to kernel mode, usually due to traps (software interrupts), and while interrupt routines execute, it saves the context of main process in **trapframe**. But during a hardware interrupt, usually from timer, which executes process schedule procedure, it saves the context in **schedule context**.

What exactly is the different type of data being stored in them?